# Signal does not allow sharing to other apps

Tags: signal-private-messenger

In my installation of the Signal messenger, I can share images and videos to other apps, like email apps and the like. However my wife cannot, the option in the "three dot menu" just does not exist, only forwarding inside Signal. All our permissions are set the same and we have the same version installed.

What can be the problem? How can she be able to forward images to other apps?

Comment: We once had someone here with a similar problem. He had an app installed that caused the share-menu to crash. May be it is similar in your case. I would start searching the problem not in signal but in the list of apps that are e.g. used for sharing images. Check in the Android settings the default app for images. There you should be able to see the list of apps installed that should be shown in the sharing list. You could also check `adb logcat` while opening the sharing menu (ad requires USB connection to PC, installed Android SDK and enabled developer options + adb on device).

Comment: It does work the other way around

Comment: So for example sharing from WhatsApp to Signal

Comment: could you please add the Signal version of your wife's and your device? And a screenshot what you can see?

Answer (score 0):

Signal v 6.21.3:

I thought I had the same problem but I realized when I open the photo then **short tap again** I see the share symbol in my bottom left corner:

[image]

Maybe your wife can update to v 6.21.3 as well.